# Ember.js: saving a record destroy belongsTo relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model, lets call it `house`, and an other, `kitchen`. When I try to save the `house` model, its relationships `belongsTo()` to `kitchen` is destroyed.

`house` has a `belongsTo()` relationships to `kitchen`, like that:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    kitchen: DS.belongsTo('kitchen', {polymorphic:true}),
});
```

`kitchen` is a very simple model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I am creating my record, filling it and finally saving it in a component. This is the function associated to it.

```
 createHouse() {
    this.createKitchen().then(() => { // this will create, fill and save a kitchen record
          this.createAnSetHouse(); // this will create and fill a house record as 'house'
          console.log(this.get('house').get('kitchen')); // this properly get the kitchen record
          this.get('house').save().then(() => {
              console.log(this.get('house').get('kitchen')); // and here the relationships is set to null ???
          / * rest of the function * / 
    }
```

As you can see in the snippets above, once, I save the `jhouse` record, the relationships is set to null, even if it was properly set beforehand.

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned it, this is the payload that my server receive:
  `"content": { "attributes": { "kitchen_id": null, "name": "myName" } }`

Any tips is appreciated.

**FINAL EDIT**

I figured out how to solve it, I was doing some weird things with my promise in `createKitchen`, I had a `Ember.RSVP.defer()` that was `resolve()` even if the `kitchen` record was not yet saved...
The snippets above should work fine for most you, if you don't do some weird things with promise.

Answer (score 0):

As an educated guess,I think your API response to

> this.get('house').save()

is a packet without the kitchen relation, which then overwrites the local model.

If you look at the response in your developer console, what do you see?

Also: I don't see the kitchen getting persisted in that code, unless your API is implicitly persisting it when you save the house.

Comment: I should have mentioned it, this is the payload that my server receive: 
`"content": {
    "attributes": {
        "kitchen_id": null,
        "name": "myName"
    }
}`

Comment: I am using an adapter that retrieve the 'kitchen' id, and then  push only the id, the backend will handle it.

Comment: For the console, the first call  return: `content: Class {__ember1510241294711: "ember1457", store: Class, _internalModel: InternalModel, currentState: {…}, …},` and the second call: `content: null`.

Comment: And `house` in the `this.get('house').save()` is a record that I created like that: `this.set('house', this.get('store').createRecord('house');`

Comment: No I mean what is being sent over the network - if you are using chrome check the response in the 'Network' tab to the house post.